# How to have variables in CSS and set them from controller dynamically during runtime in UI5?

Tags: javascript, css, sapui5

I want to position an actionsheet(ActionSheet does not accept arguments for positioning while opening as of now) using `addStyleClass` function. As this function only accepts CSS class name as I read in API and not unnamed classes directly in the argument, I need to have different value of top property in my CSS class (webapp/css/Style.css) which would be like -

```
.relationActionSheetStyle {

top: iPageY;

}
```

`iPageY` is obtained during runtime from a right click event in the controller function.
How can I pass value to `iPageY` variable in CSS dynamically and then use `myActionSheetControl.addStyleClass(relationActionSheetStyle)`?

Answer (score 0):

Add below css in you style.css file

```
:root {
   --myVar: 100px;
}

.relationActionSheetStyle {
   top: --myVar;
}
```

After adding addStyleClass to action sheet, use the statement below to update the variable

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--myVar", 300 + "px");
```

Adjust the variable naming according to your needs.